# stop double full stops in a number field

Tags: php, validation, numbers

I have a user with a stammer. She often enters numbers as 2..00

```
'ILQtyNew' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
    'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION)
```

does not strip the extra full stop out.
Is there something I can do rather than a str_replace as it would be rather tedious

Comment: You could suggest that the user pays more attention

Comment: where they are entering, add a note above that box :-`please input in the format like 2.00 `, or add javascript to alrert that they added two dots

Comment: Add some javascript validation to alert the user to the fact they have added 2 dots

Comment: Thanks guys.  I was hoping there was another flag I could add to stop it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using

floatval(ILQtyNew)

before I update the database

Thank you for your interest